# Simplify conditional if statement c#

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an if statement that becoming a bit cumbersome. I want to know if there's a better way of going about multiple similar if statements such as combining into one or using a different conditional statement such as a while or do loop. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
if (options.OpenCloseOverridesOptions != null && !options.OpenCloseOverridesOptions.AreEqual(OpenCloseOverridesOptions))
            return false;

        if (options.DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions != null && !options.DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions.AreEqual(DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions))
            return false;

        if (options.PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions != null && !options.PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions.AreEqual(PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions))
            return false;

        if (options.PickupServiceWindowOverridesOptions != null && !options.PickupServiceWindowOverridesOptions.AreEqual(PickupServiceWindowOverridesOptions))
            return false;

        if (options.DeliveryServiceWindowOverridesOptions != null && !options.DeliveryServiceWindowOverridesOptions.AreEqual(DeliveryServiceWindowOverridesOptions))
            return false;

        if (options.ServiceWindowOverridesOptions != null && !options.ServiceWindowOverridesOptions.AreEqual(ServiceWindowOverridesOptions))
            return false;

        if (options.LineItemsOptions != null && !options.LineItemsOptions.AreEqual(LineItemsOptions))
            return false;
```

the rundown is I am basically checking if an object is null, if not use an extension method to determine if a similar object is equal. (I'm not overriding isEquals and getHashCode ). if the object is null I cannot call the areEquals extension method so that check is necessary.

Comment: Why refactor. I think it's clair like this

Comment: If you have a functional program, you could submit this over to the folks at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, you could simplify your null checks with the null conditional operator (`?.`).

Comment: there is the potential for more options to be evaluated so I'm just thinking of long-term readability and maintainability. AlsoI haven't used stack in ages and apparently, there's a StackOverflow for code review...Should this be there instead?

Comment: ok @BrootsWaymb you answered my question as I entered it...awesome

Comment: @BrootsWaymb idea is vividly illustrated in mm8 example. I will try it out, thanks for the prompt responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return `bool` you can return the condition directly.

We can use another skill ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) let! into the statement, that will reverse all logic, let the code more clear.

```
return  
    (options.OpenCloseOverridesOptions == null || options.OpenCloseOverridesOptions.AreEqual(OpenCloseOverridesOptions)) &&
    (options.DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions == null || options.DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions.AreEqual(DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions)) &&
    (options.PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions == null || options.PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions.AreEqual(PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions))&&
    (options.PickupServiceWindowOverridesOptions == null || options.PickupServiceWindowOverridesOptions.AreEqual(PickupServiceWindowOverridesOptions) &&
    (options.DeliveryServiceWindowOverridesOptions == null || options.DeliveryServiceWindowOverridesOptions.AreEqual(DeliveryServiceWindowOverridesOptions)&&
    (options.ServiceWindowOverridesOptions == null || options.ServiceWindowOverridesOptions.AreEqual(ServiceWindowOverridesOptions)&&
    (options.LineItemsOptions == null || options.LineItemsOptions.AreEqual(LineItemsOptions)
```

Comment: Ill give this a try

Comment: @#$% this is good thanks, man. Thanks, everyone for responding. So simple howd I not think of this

Answer (score 1):

Use the [safe-navigation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) that was introduced in C#6 and a single `if` statement with several conditions, e.g.:

```
if (options.OpenCloseOverridesOptions?.AreEqual(OpenCloseOverridesOptions) != true
    || options.DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions?.AreEqual(DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions) != true
    || options.PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions?.AreEqual(PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions) != true)
    return false;
```

Comment: thanks for the response instead of the or operator should I use and (&&) because I need all of them to be true if not return false

Comment: @DylanGodfrey: According to the code snippet you posted, you want to return false if any *options are not equal, don't you?

Comment: yes, I wrote up a unit test. Im converting my code to mirror your response

Comment: you should mention safe-navigation is introduced in c# 6.0. what about the previous versions? it will be a flaw

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (options.OpenCloseOverridesOptions != null && !options.OpenCloseOverridesOptions?.AreEqual(OpenCloseOverridesOptions)
        || !options.DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions?.AreEqual(DeliveryOpenCloseOverridesOptions)
        || !options.PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions?.AreEqual(PickupOpenCloseOverridesOptions))
        return false;
```